# echo example compilation error :ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I have those functions in some open source lib called uWebSockets 
any way I try to run its simple example using Visual Studio 2013.

The function I try to call looks like this:

```
template <bool isServer>
void Group<isServer>::onMessage(std::function<void (WebSocket<isServer>, char *, size_t, OpCode)> handler) {
    messageHandler = handler;
}
```

and the example looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    uWS::Hub h;


    h.onMessage([](uWS::WebSocket<uWS::SERVER> ws, char *message, size_t length, uWS::OpCode opCode) {
        ws.send(message, length, opCode);
    });

    h.listen(3000);
    h.run();
}
```

The error I'm getting looks like this :

```
1>D:\dev\cpp\server\uWebSockets\git\uWebSockets\uWebSockets\examples\echo.cpp(9): error C2668: 'uWS::Group<false>::onMessage' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          d:\dev\cpp\server\uwebsockets\git\uwebsockets\uwebsockets\src\Group.h(69): could be 'void uWS::Group<false>::onMessage(std::function<void (uWS::WebSocket<false>,char *,size_t,uWS::OpCode)>)'
1>          d:\dev\cpp\server\uwebsockets\git\uwebsockets\uwebsockets\src\Group.h(69): or       'void uWS::Group<true>::onMessage(std::function<void (uWS::WebSocket<true>,char *,size_t,uWS::OpCode)>)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(main::<lambda_f789fc974d6d87c4a2444e6ded66c2a0>)'
```

Question:
Can I over come the error without upgrading the Visual Studio to 2015?
or it is not related to the compiler version?

UPDATE : 
if i set it to : `h.onMessage<true>`  or  `h.onMessage<uWS::SERVER>`
im getting : 
This error :

```
1>D:\dev\cpp\server\uWebSockets\git\uWebSockets\uWebSockets\examples\echo.cpp(10): error C2678: binary '>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'bool' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          could be 'built-in C++ operator>(void (__cdecl *)(uWS::WebSocket<true>,char *,size_t,uWS::OpCode), void (__cdecl *)(uWS::WebSocket<true>,char *,size_t,uWS::OpCode))'
1>          or       'built-in C++ operator>(void (__stdcall *)(uWS::WebSocket<true>,char *,size_t,uWS::OpCode), void (__stdcall *)(uWS::WebSocket<true>,char *,size_t,uWS::OpCode))'
1>          or       'built-in C++ operator>(void (__fastcall *)(uWS::WebSocket<true>,char *,size_t,uWS::OpCode), void (__fastcall *)(uWS::WebSocket<true>,char *,size_t,uWS::OpCode))'
1>          or       'built-in C++ operator>(void (__vectorcall *)(uWS::WebSocket<true>,char *,size_t,uWS::OpCode), void (__vectorcall *)(uWS::WebSocket<true>,char *,size_t,uWS::OpCode))'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(bool, main::<lambda_f789fc974d6d87c4a2444e6ded66c2a0>)'
```

Comment: Try `h.onMessage<true>(...);`. And why `WebSocket<uWS::SERVER>`, is it the same as `WebSocket<true>`?

Comment: What is the type of `Hub`? Does it perhaps inherit both `Group<true>` and `Group<false>`?

Comment: @ ilotXXI the h.onMessage<true> not working gives more errors
I updated the question

Comment: @molbdnilo `Hub` does inherit both those things. It is the uWebSockets (https://github.com/uWebSockets/uWebSockets) project which you can find on github. I tried to build it on VS2015 but it's not straightforward as you need a working OpenSSL and libuv but I chopped parts out until it did compile - so I think updating to VS2015 might be your only option. Hopefully someone else can add more info.

Comment: what you did there ? i tried with VS2015 but still i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors, after minor fix I got it running:

```
int main()
{   uWS::Hub h;

   h.onMessage([](uWS::WebSocket<uWS::SERVER>* ws, char *message, size_t length, uWS::OpCode opCode) {
        ws->send(message, length, opCode);
    });

    h.listen(3000);
    h.run();
}
```